# Differences between call, push+ret and push+jump in assembly

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I have a trace instruction and want to extract function calls and returns.

I found that except `call` instruction, `push`+`jmp` and `push`+`ret` can be used for function call? At first I want to be sure is that correct? and if yes what are the differences between them?

Also if `push`+`ret` is kind of call so what would be the end or return of a function? Seeing only `ret` without `push` instruction before it?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you are correct.

When a `call` is issued, the return address pushed onto the stack is the next address where execution should continue (the address immediately following the current instruction).  In essence it is an atomic `push` followed by a `jmp`.

This means that if you manually `push` and then `jmp`, the function that you jump into can later `ret` and, provided all stack access in the function is balanced, it will return to the address that you previously pushed.

Similarly, you can `push` and then `ret` to simulate a call return, but this does not set you up to be able to later return again.  This type of behavior is more commonly done to throw off disassemblers, making it more difficult to determine which address the code is actually heading to with a simple disassembler.

Comment: "This type of behavior is more commonly done to throw off disassemblers" do you know if IDA Pro has any functionality to correctly interpret these tactics as calls/returns? From a general perspective, in what direction would you suggest one go to disassemble code that employs this obfuscation tactic? edit: a bit more searching yielded this thread which references your answer and answers my question: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10911/automatically-decode-pushret-call-into-jmp

Answer (score 8):

In simplified terms:

**call *address***

This will push the updated program counter (which points to the instruction after the `call`) onto the stack then jump to the *address* indicated (addressing modes may apply).

**ret**

This instruction internally pops and address off the stack and jumps to it. This is nicely matched with `call` so it can return to the instruction after the prior `call`.

**jmp *address***

This simply jumps to the given *address* (addressing modes may apply). It doesn't do anything with the stack at all.

---

So, you can also do this:

```
push address
ret
```

Which will pop and jump to the *address* that was pushed onto the stack as described above. It's a clever way to do an indirect jump in a microprocessor that doesn't support indirect addressing modes in their jump instructions.

The sequence:

```
push address
jmp someplace
```

Will simply jump to *someplace* and not affect the stack or use the *address* that was pushed onto the stack.  If *address* is the instruction after the `jmp`, this is roughly equivalent to `call someplace`.

For instruction sets that don't support an indirect addressing jump, I've seen this nice little work-around:

```
push address
ret
```

Which will jump to whatever `address` is.

Comment: Unusual variations of these are often used when the author wants to obscure the true functionality of the code (e.g., malware and "copy-protected" commercial software).

Comment: Isn't `ret` essentially `pop and jump indirect to the popped address`?

Comment: @JohnHascall yeah it is... "duh" on my part. :p I was thinking "no `call`, no `ret`". :)

Comment: Note that `push` / `ret` is bad for performance, causing branch misprediction now and in future `ret` instructions because of the unbalanced call/ret.  CPUs predict `ret` with an internal stack that assumes a matching `call`, because that's what normal code does.  http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/